# C++ return type-deduction with shorthand IF statement problem

Tags: if-statement, g++, type-deduction

Why in C++ return type deduction doesn't work with short if?

Here are the example code. (Compiler g++-10 v.10.0.1 20200416)

```
struct Point{
  int x;
  int y;
};

Point test() {
  // In C++20 works
  return {0,1};

  // In C++20 works
  return 1 ? Point{0,0} : Point{1,1};

  // In C++20 don't work
  return 1 ? {0,0} : {1,1};
}
```

I think it should be valid in all cases :)
Is there some magic to force type-deduction?

Answer (score 0):

The return statement needs to directly return the object. That is the return expects an Point. if its in the format `return {0,1}`, the `{0,1}` is cast to point,
 but `return 1 ? {0,0} : {1,1}`, the return statement cant implicitly cast to point, so you have to make new objects to return. eg `return 1 ? Point{0,0} : Point{1,1};`